# Turbolinks causing a "jquery-ujs has already been loaded!" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a newish Rails 4 app which contains *no* custom Javascript - the folders `app/assets/javascripts`, `lib/assets/javascripts` and `vendor/assets/javascripts` are all empty (apart from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`).

When I click around the app I keep getting the error `jquery-ujs has already been loaded!` in the JS console. It happens every time I hit the "back" button, and sometimes when I click a normal link (although I can't make it happen consistently.)

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

When I remove turbolinks from application.js, I stop getting the error... so turbolinks appears to be the culprit.

Is this a bug with turbolinks, or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'paperclip-meta', github: 'y8/paperclip-meta'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.9'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.2.0'
  gem 'json_spec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'wirb'
end
```

Changing around the order of the `require`s in application.js doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you're including your *scripts* in the page `body`.

See this issue for more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/143

From the [turbolinks readme](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#evaluating-script-tags):

> As a rule of thumb when switching to Turbolinks, move all of your javascript tags    inside the `head` and then work backwards, only moving javascript code back to the body if absolutely necessary. If you have any script tags in the body you do not want to be re-evaluated then you can set the `data-turbolinks-eval` attribute to `false`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-turbolinks-eval=false>
  console.log("I'm only run once on the initial page load");
</script>
```

Comment: Got it! I had my `<%= javascript_include_tag ... %>` before my closing `</body>` tag - moving it inside the `<head>` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I happened to have the javascript tag in the body of a layout. That really messed me up.

Comment: I know that the question was answered a long time ago, but I want to collaborate with my case... I had a problem like this, but in production, after pushing some updates in CoffeeScript files. And the problem was very simple: cache. Probably the page tried to load both the old and the new bundled script file. It was solved, for my browser, by hitting Ctrl+F5 to ignore cached resources.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and after doing some hit and trial i found the sequence of javascript files matters.

The working sequence is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
```

Hope, this solution will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that I had It was that I copied the <%= render 'layouts/head'%> twice!, in the head and in the body. check the laouts/application.html.erb file

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had included these written twice so it was loading twice. Once in application.js `//= require jquery` and once in application.html.erb as a script tag.

Comment: Do you mean you had both lines written in 2 separate places?

Comment: This sometimes pertains to adding webpack and having a separate front-end, like Vue.js or React