# jquery-ujs has already been loaded rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

So I am trying to integrate google maps into my rails app ( keep in mind that it is the first time i do so and I am a rails beginner and I do not understand Ruby code very well ).

code for maps

> ```
> <!-- 
>     You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
>     When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
>         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
>     After your sign up replace the key in the URL below or paste in the new script tag that Google provides.
> -->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRKcd8KX82m0q47qSGB9Ryh79jqzjOpAk&sensor=false"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
>     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
>
>     function init() {
>         // Basic options for a simple Google Map
>         // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
>         var mapOptions = {
>             // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
>             zoom: 12,
>
>             // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
>             center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.495040, -73.614371), // Montreal
>
>             // How you would like to style the map. 
>             // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
>             styles: [{"stylers":[{"hue":"#16a085"},{"saturation":0}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":80},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}]
>         };
>         // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
>         // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
>         var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
>
>         // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
>         var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
>     }
> </script> </head> <body>
> <!-- The element that will contain our Google Map. This is used in both the Javascript and CSS above. -->
> <div class="innerborder">
>           <div id="map"></div>        </div>
> ```

For some reason, it tries to load jquery-ujs twice whenever I click on the page that contains the maps. Here is my application.js include tree

> //= require jquery  //= require jquery_ujs  //= require turbolinks 
>   //=require_tree .

Weird, keep getting this :
Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded!

Any ideas for me ?

Thanks!

Comment: `require_tree .` is loading all the files in the directory tree.

Comment: Hi,

removing require_tree . has not fixed this.
I still get

Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded! jquery.js?body=1:517
Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded! jquery.js?body=1:517
Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded! jquery.js?body=1:517


Thank you though!

Comment: are you also using a gem that is including the script?

Comment: I don't know. Is there a way to find out ? here is a list of my personal gems 

# personal gems
gem 'activerecord-tableless'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0' 
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'better_errors' 
gem 'quiet_assets' 
gem "font-awesome-rails"


Thanks again!

Comment: @HarrisRobin U found issue?? I am getting d same

Comment: No, i did not solve it. Ended up using g4maps gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is from the turbolinks. try disabling them. i had a lot of issues with them and ended up dropping them from a project. you can use this gem to make a work around, but first try with them disabled if you still want to try:
https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: I think with the likes of Backbone, Ember Angular etc... I don't think turbolinks should be included by default in rails. Thanks for your help this worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well and it looks like @Cremz was right with the turbolinks. I found the  solution to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684846/turbolinks-causing-a-jquery-ujs-has-already-been-loaded-error), but in short you are most likely loading your turbolinks in the body, and if so move them into the head tag.

Comment: This was my exact issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i did not want to touch any gem or config cause everything else is working fine so i wrote some js to reload the page if the turbolink object restorationIdentifier is duplicated when window.onpopstate is trigger

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
 var turbi=window.history.state.turbolinks.restorationIdentifier;
 window.onpopstate= function(){
  if(window.history.state.turbolinks.restorationIdentifier==turbi){
   window.location.reload();
  }
 }
    
    });
```